# Going backwards in nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models: posts, comments and questions. I am trying to show the title of a post that a question belongs to on the question index page. In a sense go backwards through the resources.
Here is what the routes look like:

```
resources :posts do
resources :comments do
 end
end

resources :comments do
 resources :questions do
 end
end
```

Right now this is how i am trying to do it in my questions index page but am getting an 'undefined method title error':

```
 <% @post.title %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, that `@post` is nil on question index page. Routes just help with routing, nestings should be wired within models via `has_many` and `belongs_to`.

To "go back" try `@question.post.title`

BTW, do you have title field at Post model?

Comment: Ok thanks i got it. I had to play around a little with yours and  <%= @comment.post.title %> ended up doing the trick. Thanks for the help!